# How to determine academic level?

Tags: internship

I have to complete a form for my internship.
A question on the form reads "On the first day of the above mentioned student’s employment, his/her academic level will be:___________".
Suggested answers are: Freshman, Sophomore, Junior, Senior, Master’s, Ph.D.

I will complete my first year of Master's by the start of the internship.

Comment: Is there some reason you don't think "Masters" is the right choice, given that you'll be a Masters student and that the form suggests that as an answer?

Comment: I do not have Master's degree yet.

Comment: Is this in English or translated?

Comment: Given the other possible answers, it sounds like it is asking if you are Master's *student*. If you really don't think there is an appropriate response, then contact them and ask.

Comment: Since the first 4 options are not degrees, and the sentence explicitly asks about the status of the "student", you can then read the last two options as "master's student", "Ph.D. student", etc. That's how I'd read this if it were in the US and natively written in English, anyway.

Comment: This is a form from a US lab. So, I assume, this is English. I am asking if I can put "Master's" in the gap. I have indicated in the question that I *am* Master's student, but I don't know about my *academic level*.

Answer (score 1):

Put Master's.

The reason is because you're a Master's student, and they're presumably asking for your current status as opposed to your highest completed degree. To see this, consider the PhD option. If you've completed a PhD degree, then you're no longer a student, in which case the first part of the sentence is incorrect. But if they want you to use your highest completed degree, then literally nobody could possibly fill the blank with PhD. The only sensible option is they want your current status, and since you're a Master's student, you use that.